# How to make a user stay on same page once they log in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I am having an issue on how to make it where users who are viewing any page can log in on the page they are viewing and it stays on that page.  How would this be accomplished?

Below is a single line I am currently using, however, if on any page and a user logs in, they are redirected to their profile.  How can I set this line where it logs the user in, and it stays on that same page they are viewing?  So in other words, are not redirected to their profile...

PHP:

```
header("Location: members.php?id=" . $_SESSION['username']);
```

If more info is needed, let me know and I can make an edit ;)

Comment: I believe you are after `AJAX`

Comment: I could take the long way around this and simply create on each page the location desired, however, one would think that this would be as simple as the 1 line I provided above which would need changed to make work and it would work across all pages...I don't think `AJAX` would help out at all in this case.  It should purely be done with php one would think...

Comment: PHP only will require a page reload or a double redirect, as mentioned below. To avoid these, AJAX is needed

Answer (score 2):

Have the login form submit the address of the current page. Then you can simply redirect back to that address when the login succeeds, e.g.

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="curpage" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" />
   <input type="text" name="username" />
   <input type="password" name="password" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>

if ($login_is_successful) {
   header("Location: {$_POST['curpage']}");
}
```

You could try using the referer, but since that's not sent by all browser, and is not always accurate, you're better off sing alternate "current location" tracking means, such as the above hidden form field.

Answer (score 1):

When they click on the login button you can read the url and save it to a varibale and redirect them to this url.

So instead of

```
header("Location: members.php?id=" . $_SESSION['username']);
```

you can use sth. like:

```
 header("Location: $last_page);
```

Comment: I'd have to create that variable though wouldn't I? `$last_page` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
you can create a php file with this code and include into your code like this 
session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"]))
{
$usuario = $_SESSION["usuario"];
else{
header('Location: members.php?id=" . $_SESSION['username']');
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include ('session.php'); 
?>
```

to avoid using same code in every page

Comment: That's what I plan on doing, "to avoid using same code in every page", quick question: what and where did `$_SESSION["usuario"];` come from?  What does `usuario` mean?